# how to fetch data from Func using generic list and linq

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, generic-list, func

I am new to C#.

I have a class `account` with `name` and `balance`.
I made a list of those accounts, and now what I'm trying to do is to somehow get all users whose balance is greater than `20000` using `Func`.

I am aware of that my code ma be wrong, so please, help me out.

```
class entry
{       
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<account> list1 = new List<account>()
        {
            new savingAcc("a",50000),
            new currentAcc("b",30000),
            new savingAcc("c",80000),
            new currentAcc("d",10000),
            new savingAcc("e",7000),
            new savingAcc("f",85000)     

        };          

        Func<List<account>,List<account>> myhand = mySorting.mysal;
        /* here something which will print my data as foreach is not working */
    }
}

public class mySorting
{
    public static List<account> mysal(List<account> lis)
    {
        return (from i in lis where i._Balance > 50000 select i).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the foreach work? What makes you think so?

Comment: i dont know. its showing that foreach doesnt support Func something like that.

Comment: @Akshay: Do you mean `mySorting.mysal()` within your `Main`?!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, without using `Func<>`

```
foreach(account in mySorting.mysal(list1)) {
    /* do your stuff on an account */
}
```

Or better

```
foreach(account in (from i in lis where i._Balance > 50000 select i)) {
    /* do your stuff on an account */
}
```

Or even better

```
(from i in lis where i._Balance > 50000 select i).ForEach(a => a.DoStuff());
```

**Edit:**

With `Func<>` you could use

```
Func<List<account>, List<account>> myhand = mySorting.mysal;
foreach(account in myhand(list1)) {
    /* do your stuff on an account */
}
```

or

```
Func<List<account>, List<account>> myhand = mySorting.mysal;
myhand(list1).ForEach(a => a.DoStuff());
```

Comment: Thank you verry much ... it worked.. realy sorry cant vote for u as my rep is less .. but il def return to this post once my rep will be up